# The difference in the work of two similar queries with GROUP BY clause WITH ROLLUP in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Please, help me to understand why the following two queries return different results. The difference in queries is only in using DATE_FORMAT function in GROUP BY clause.

Query 1:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(T0.ET,'%Y/%m/%d %H%i'), SUM(T0.AT)
FROM(SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(second,(SEQ -1)*300, STR_TO_DATE('20170809135000','%Y%m%d%H%i%s')) ET, 1 AT
   FROM SEQ_1_TO_10
   WHERE SEQ <= 5) T0
   group by T0.ET with rollup
```

Result 1:

```
'2017/08/09 1350', '1'
'2017/08/09 1355', '1'
'2017/08/09 1400', '1'
'2017/08/09 1405', '1'
'2017/08/09 1410', '1'
NULL, '5'
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(T0.ET,'%Y/%m/%d %H%i') , SUM(T0.AT)
FROM(SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(second,(SEQ -1)*300, STR_TO_DATE('20170809135000','%Y%m%d%H%i%s')) ET, 1 AT
   FROM SEQ_1_TO_10
   WHERE SEQ <= 5) T0
   group by  DATE_FORMAT(T0.ET,'%Y/%m/%d %H%i') with rollup
```

Result 2:

```
'2017/08/09 1350', '1'
'2017/08/09 1355', '1'
'2017/08/09 1400', '1'
'2017/08/09 1405', '1'
'2017/08/09 1410', '1'
'2017/08/09 1410', '5'
```

EXPLAIN SELECT for both queries are the same:

```
id,  select_type, table,         type,    possible_keys, key,      key_len, ref,  rows, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE',    'SEQ_1_TO_10', 'range', 'PRIMARY',     'PRIMARY','8',     NULL, '5',  'Using where; Using index; Using filesort'
```

Comment: What data type is to.et?

Comment: @P.Salmon, ET is TIMESTAMP which is returned by TIMESTAMPADD.

Comment: @P.Salmon, any ideas?

Comment: Ideas yes proof no.

Comment: @P.Salmon, Please, share.

Comment: Both queries are nonsensical, as neither performs any kind of aggregation.

Comment: @Used_By_Already, this queries don't require data, data is generated in queries. SEQ_1_TO_10 generates sequence from 1 to 10. Or instead you can use table with one column with values from 1 to 10.

Comment: yes, I realized that as soon as I asked it, unfortunately dbfiddle.uk is the only Maria.db I have access to is 10.2 I think you need 10.3. can you add `, 1 as data` as a new column, and `, sum(data)` in the outer query. Just so we can see the actual rollup (if any)

Comment: @Used_By_Already, Done. Please see updated queries

Comment: thanks!. weird, result 2 is v.unexpected.

Comment: @Used_By_Already Agreed , unexpected behaviour for rollup last row appears to last date where I would expect null.

Comment: @P.Salmon yes, exactly. seems like the date_format() produces a memory effect. *I wonder what would happen for more than 1 level of rollup?*

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for both queries.

Comment: @RickJames, I've added result of EXPLAIN SELECT to the question, but the both EXPLAIN SELECT are the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 13
Server version: 10.1.14-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT typ ,DATE_FORMAT(T.ET,'%Y/%m/%d %H%i') et, sum(1)
    -> FROM(
    -> SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(second,(SEQ -1)*300, STR_TO_DATE('20170809135000','%Y%m%d%H%i%s'))  ET,
    -> case when seq % 2 = 0 then 'a' else 'b' end as typ
    ->    FROM SEQ_1_TO_10
    ->    WHERE SEQ <= 5
    -> ) T
    -> group by typ,DATE_FORMAT(T.ET,'%Y/%m/%d %H%i') with rollup;
+------+-----------------+--------+
| typ  | et              | sum(1) |
+------+-----------------+--------+
| a    | 2017/08/09 1355 |      1 |
| a    | 2017/08/09 1405 |      1 |
| a    | 2017/08/09 1405 |      2 |
| b    | 2017/08/09 1350 |      1 |
| b    | 2017/08/09 1400 |      1 |
| b    | 2017/08/09 1410 |      1 |
| b    | 2017/08/09 1410 |      3 |
| NULL | 2017/08/09 1410 |      5 |
+------+-----------------+--------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @Used_By_Already strange the sub totals are fine but the dates are very clingy.

Comment: indeed they are... looks "buggish" to me